# How to set the value of a HTML file field?

Tags: php, html

> **Note:**
>
> The answers & comments below reflect the state of legacy browsers in 2009. Now you can actually set the value of the file input element dynamically/programatically using JavaScript in 2017.
>
> See the answer in this question for details as well as a demo:
> [How to set file input value programatically (i.e.: when drag-dropping files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47515232/584192)

In HTML we can set the value of a textfield by writing :

```
<input type="text" name="doc_intitule" maxlength="100" size="24" value="<?php echo $ret['doc_intitule']; ?>">
```

But how to set the value of a `file` field ?

Comment: What's the exact use case of this? Do you plan to display a previously uploaded file or do you want to set some kind of default?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326683/php-remember-file-field-contents

Comment: why you 'd like to do that? what is the business case? The file control is used to enable the user to upload a file only. Instead, do you want the user to download a file ?

Comment: There is no duplicate : I didn't post this thread to other tags !

Comment: Duplication has nothing to do with tags: it has to do with asking a question that has been asked before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to this

[How to keep input type=file field value after failed validation in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967916/how-to-keep-input-type-file-field-value-after-failed-validation-in-asp-net-mvc)

As far as I am aware of, you are not meant to pre-set file field values for security purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You **cant** set value of file field by any means.
See here: [info](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html#value)

Answer (score 3):

You can't set a default value to a file field.

This is a security thing: you can just make a form submit by code, so you would be able to force a user to upload a file without their knowledge.