# symfony2 file lost upon form error

Tags: file, validation, symfony, upload, doctrine

I am using a standard implementation of file upload in connection with doctrine, as per the example on the symfony2 website tutorials.

When my upload form encounters an error in validation, and sends the user back to the form with error messages, it looses the file chosen for upload, although if I var_dump my $entity->file I can see that it has the file...

```
    //if form is valid, do some stuff... if not:
    else {

        //var_dump($entity->file); //This works, I get my file
        //die;

        //Get and check the folder chosen as parent
        $entity->setFolder( $this->checkFolderId($request->request->get('folder')) ); //will cause die() if folder doesn't belong to this company

        $folders = $this->getFolders();

        return $this->render('BizTVMediaManagementBundle:Image:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
            'folders' => $folders,
            'fileExists' => $fileExists,
        ));

    }
```

After this is put to the twig view, there is nothing in the file field.

Here is my entity...

```
<?php

namespace BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\Image
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name

     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer $width
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="width", type="integer")
     */
    private $width;

    /**
     * @var integer $height
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="height", type="integer")
     */
    private $height;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
    * @var object BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company
    *  
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
    */
    protected $company;     

    /**
    * @var object BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\Folder
    *  
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\Folder")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="folder", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
    */
    protected $folder;


    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
     public $file;


    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->file) {
            // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
            $this->path = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
        // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
        // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

        unset($this->file);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }    

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();

    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/images';
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set width
     *
     * @param integer $width
     */
    public function setWidth($width)
    {
        $this->width = $width;
    }

    /**
     * Get width
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getWidth()
    {
        return $this->width;
    }

    /**
     * Set height
     *
     * @param integer $height
     */
    public function setHeight($height)
    {
        $this->height = $height;
    }

    /**
     * Get height
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getHeight()
    {
        return $this->height;
    }

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * Set company
     *
     * @param BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company $company
     */
    public function setCompany(\BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company $company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;
    }

    /**
     * Get company
     *
     * @return BizTV\BackendBundle\Entity\company 
     */
    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    /**
     * Set folder
     *
     * @param BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\Folder $folder
     */
    public function setFolder(\BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\Folder $folder = NULL)
    {
        $this->folder = $folder;
    }

    /**
     * Get folder
     *
     * @return BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Entity\Folder 
     */
    public function getFolder()
    {
        return $this->folder;
    }


}
```

And the form:

```
<?php

namespace BizTV\MediaManagementBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    function __construct($createAction=0) {
        $this->createAction = $createAction;    
    }   

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {

        $createAction = $this->createAction;

        if ($createAction) {        
            $builder
                ->add('file')
            ;
        }

        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Namn'))
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'biztv_mediamanagementbundle_imagetype';
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide information how you try to output your file in twig.

Comment: are you able to resolve the issue with my answer? webPath is the property holding the path to the image after uploading. if any questions left comment otherwise accept pleae :)

Comment: I am not outputting it myself, i render a view of my form after it failed to validate, so that user can correct the missing fields, and if file was chosen i would expect it to still be there, along with the other values that were correct, leaving blank fields only for those attributes that failed to validate.

Comment: this is a more complicated operation as the persistance of the image is only done in the example on post-persist and post-update! The confusing part of your answer was the ... although the var dump shows it has the file ... okay so your entity is NOT persisted because validation failed therefore file not saved ... then i'll rework my answer :)

Comment: Oh, but I don't want to save the image on the server in case of form validation failure, all I want is for the user not to have to browse out the file again in case he forgot to put a name in the name box of the form. Can I access the original path in some way?

Comment: Oh, it seems this can simply not be done, looked around and foun this thread http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/66876-how-to-find-full-path-of-a-file-upload-field-in-a-form-filesfile1/ I guess it has to do with how browsers work around this security-wise...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, for security purposes, set a file for the upload field. See here for more info. [How to set the value of a HTML file field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513243/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-html-file-field)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you are trying to access the **file** property of your entity in twig. Please take a quick look at your upload function.

```
/**
* @ORM\PostPersist()
* @ORM\PostUpdate()
*/
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
    // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
    // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

    unset($this->file);
}
```

As you can see the file property is being unset after the upload and persist operation has completed.

Now to have twig show your actual image you have to use the **webPath** property as this is the generated url to your newly uploaded image.

File uploading can be handled a bit easier with the [Dustin10/VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) which also supports file system abstraction with [KnpLabs/Gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: On line 4 of my first sample code i can still access my file, so clearly it is still there when the controller goes to renderng the view. I just create a formview from my form object (imageType, as code included in the question). So if user forgets to name file, the chosen folder is "still" in the form after going back to the form for cmpleting with name, but the chosen Image is not there.