# Prevent HTML file field from being delete after PHP validation roundtrip

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a HTML file field `<input name="File" id="FileName" type="file"/>`. When I submit the form, I do receive the file, all fine. However, when I validate the user's input and cannot accept the values provided, I will need another round trip. As usual, I will redisplay the form plus error messages.

For `text field` or `textarea` I can set the (already) provided value, e.g. by `value` or just `echo` the value in the textarea. **How could I do the same for `file` fields?** I want to avoid that the user always has to reselect the file in the browser.

-- added --

Comments below are right - there are workarounds described in the mentioned SO questions:

1. [PHP remember file field contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326683/php-remember-file-field-contents)
2. [Can you re-populate file inputs after failed form submission with PHP or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842571/can-you-re-populate-file-inputs-after-failed-form-submission-with-php-or-javascr)
3. [Restoring the value of a input type=file after failed validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205634/restoring-the-value-of-a-input-type-file-after-failed-validation)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326683/php-remember-file-field-contents

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842571/can-you-re-populate-file-inputs-after-failed-form-submission-with-php-or-javascr and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205634/restoring-the-value-of-a-input-type-file-after-failed-validation

Comment: Cris and Heapy are right, can be closed as duplicate. The workarounds provided are well explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible - you have to store the file on the server to do this. Then you can show the user a short info about the already stored file and the option to upload a new file or delete the file

Comment: Yep, seems to be right, was trying to store the path via Js, but even this failes: onChange= "alert( document.getElementById('FileName').value );" does provide a fake path, not the original upload path.