# Load the selected filename in a form textfield

Tags: php, html, forms, file, include

I am making and update DB form. I load the update form with php, rendering the data to be updated from the DB.
One of the form fields is an input textfield containing the filename of an image.
In this form I want to select a new image (), and after selecting an image, insert the selected filename of the image in the input textfield.

This is the part of **CMS_formSchema_list.php**.
It loads a list of posts, and every post has an update button.
When the button is clicked, a form action send via to itself the $_POST['update_ID'], and loads the update form populated with the data of update_ID.

```
 if (isset($_POST['update_ID']) and $_POST['update_ID']==$row_ID){
   echo '<tr style="background-color:#DDD">';
   echo '<td colspan="9"><form action="" method="post">';
   $functionDisplay = 'Editar ID:'.$_POST['update_ID'];
   echo $functionDisplay.'<br>';
   if(!include 'CMS_formSchema_edit_inline.php'){
     echo "CMS_formSchema_edit_inline.php include error!!!!"; 
   }
   echo '</td>';
   echo '</tr>';
 }
```

I perform the load of the update form via **include 'CMS_formSchema_edit_inline.php'**
Reached this point everything is fine, and working properly. I don't know why after selecting it's not populating the 'Archivo' textfield with the $_FILES['fileup']['name']. What should I do to load the filename in the textfield?.

```
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="fileup" style="width:450px;"/><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="update_ID" value="<?php echo $_POST['update_ID'] ?>"/><br/>
        <p class="white caption">Año (YYYY):<br/><input  id="year" type="text" name="year" maxlength="4" size="40" value="<?php echo $post_AÑO ?>"/><br/>
        Sección:<br/><input  id="section" type="text" name="section" maxlength="30" size="40" value="<?php echo $post_SECCION ?>"/><br/>
        Categoría:<br/><input  id="category" type="text" name="category" maxlength="30" size="40" value="<?php echo $post_CATEGORIA ?>"/><br/>
        Cliente:<br/><textarea  id="client" name="client" maxlength="100" rows="3" cols="40"><?php echo $post_CLIENTE ?></textarea><br/>
        Descripción:<br/><textarea  id="description" name="description" maxlength="200" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $post_DESCRIPCION ?></textarea><br/>
        <?php echo "update_ID (edit) = ". $_POST['update_ID'];  ?>
        Archivo:<br/><input  id="files" type="text" name="files" value="
<?php 
 if (isset($_FILES['fileup'])){
    echo basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);
 } else {
    echo $post_ARCHIVO;
 }?>"/></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: You can't. It's a security feature to not allow you to prepopulate file fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326683/php-remember-file-field-contents

Comment: Thx john, though i've searched before asking, you're right. It's the same topic, and it's fairly answered