# How to pre-fill a file type field for a form submission using the "post" method

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

I am developing a cultural web portal where users, after registering, will be able to add an article via a dedicated form.

As happens in most cultural web portals and also on social media, articles will be accompanied by a cover image that will anticipate the topic, a title and a description, as well as other fields that are not relevant here.

The CMS I have developed for the management (insertion, updating, removal) of articles has been designed for the total management in PHP of the data sent by forms. No forms are or will be loaded via JS/Ajax.

The form for saving articles will contain both mandatory and optional fields. If a mandatory field (e.g. title or text) is not filled in, the PHP script will redirect to the form, displaying the information previously entered in the fields that were filled in, to ease the user by relieving them of the task of having to re-enter all the fields again.

This choice does not create any problems for text, select and textarea type fields. It does, however, create a problem for the file type field dedicated to loading the cover image, since for security reasons it is impossible to save the local path to the image in order to retrieve it in the form and display it in the file type field.

In the form, as can be seen in the snippet below, after choosing the image it will be displayed as a preview, so that the user can check that he has chosen the correct image for his article.

Is there a way or an alternative to be able to pre-fill the file field in order to relieve the user of the task of having to choose the image again? Because the save script will retrieve all the fields via `$_POST` and the image via `$_FILES`.

I want to absolutely avoid encoding the image in base64 because some of the images that will be loaded will exceed 1280px in width and the save operation, having to transmit all the base64 encoding, would slow down a lot. Test already carried out.

**HTML  (fields not pre-filled)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('input:file').on('change', function () {

          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function () {

            $('.row').find('.preview').attr('src', reader.result);

          }

          reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

        });

      });
    </script>
    <style>
      form {
        width: 500px;
        margin: auto;
      }

      .row {
        padding: 10px 0;
      }

      .row label {
        display: block;
      }

      .row .preview {
        display: block;
        margin: 20px 0;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="save.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
          <label for="image">Image</label>
          <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
          <img src="" alt="" class="preview">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label for="text">Text</label>
          <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**HTML (pre-filled fields)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Form</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('input:file').on('change', function () {

          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function () {

            $('.row').find('.preview').attr('src', reader.result);

          }

          reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

        });

      });
    </script>
    <style>
      form {
        width: 500px;
        margin: auto;
      }

      .row {
        padding: 10px 0;
      }

      .row label {
        display: block;
      }

      .row .preview {
        display: block;
        margin: 20px 0;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="save.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
          <label for="image">Image</label>
          <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
          <img src="" alt="" class="preview">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['title'] ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label for="text">Text</label>
          <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $_SESSION['text'] ?></textarea>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Screenshot (fields not pre-filled, image chosen)**

[image]

**Screenshot (fields pre-filled, image to be chosen again)**

[image]

Comment: To me it looks like the file field is filled in, just not displaying the image.

Comment: In the CSS, I did not hide the image. As you can see from the snippet, the image is only displayed after choosing it from the local path.

Comment: The image is only displayed when the file field input "change" handler triggers.  Did you try manually triggering the change handler when the page is reloaded?

Comment: So I choose an image, the preview of which is displayed under the file field, I do not fill in the other fields, I submit the form, the PHP script sends me back because of missing data, and a change manager repopulates the file field with the previously chosen local path?

Comment: Are you looking for the **value** attribute?  You can use this in the input tag to populate an existing value

Comment: Why not process the file upload the first time around?  Eg save it on you server filesystem, and return something about it (id, filename, etc) to include as a hidden input on the form.  You can display the thumbnail from the now-saved file on the server.  Next time around your code can see there is already a file attached and does not need to reprocess it.  You might need a periodic clean up of files which were abandoned.

Comment: A bit of searching turns up several duplicate questions, all suggesting the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326683/php-remember-file-field-contents, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842571/can-you-re-populate-file-inputs-after-failed-form-submission-with-php-or-javascr, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205634/restoring-the-value-of-a-input-type-file-after-failed-validation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP remember file field contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326683/php-remember-file-field-contents)

Comment: So basically there is no alternative to: 1) Uploading via Ajax; 2) Uploading the image to the server and cleaning up the abandoned files. Both methods are impratical, but if there is no alternative..